# Генерация уникальных, хорошо различимых цветов

Tags: c#, алгоритм, цвета

Есть ли хороший алгоритм (либо веб-сервис), который может сгенерировать N цветов, которые визуально хорошо различимы между собой?

Это необходимо для отображения на одном графике несколько различных функций одновременно (N <= 70).

Comment: Смотрите в сторону системы Манселла и (более современное) цветовое пространство LAB. На самом деле 70 функций на одном графике отобразить будет сложновато, помимо цвета наверное имеет смысл дифференцировать линии

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Недавно попался один сервис, который можно для этого использовать. [Ссылка на сервис](https://davidjohnstone.net/pages/cubehelix-gradient-picker#0,30.9,1,1,1,0.8,0.2). Как вводить параметры:

- Number of swatches - сколько цветов мы хотим.
- Rotations - `(n - 1) * 0.618`, где N - количество цветов, которое мы ввели. Магическое число 0.618 - это золотое сечение, чтобы новые цвета попадали как можно дальше по оттенку от всех ранее выбранных.
- Hue - внезапно, не оттенок, а насыщенность. С плавным переходом результат не очень, поэтому наверно придется несколько раз прогонять.

Результаты работы для 21 цвета, hue 3 и hue 1:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вдруг сайт упадет и/или нужно будет разобраться на чем основан алгоритм:

<sub>Последняя ссылка с https не открывается, поэтому там http</sub>

> This is a gradient creation tool that uses the cubehelix method. This
>   is built around [chroma.js's](https://gka.github.io/chroma.js/#chroma-cubehelix) implementation of [cubehelix](http://www.mrao.cam.ac.uk/~dag/CUBEHELIX/).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Нужно будет посмотреть потом, пока времени нет. Плюс поставил, но пока не принимаю